# How do I accept Bitcoin Cash without using a third-party?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, payment, merchants

I'm looking for a way to accept Bitcoin Cash on my e-commerce site without using a third-party payment processor such as [Rocketr](https://rocketr.net/). Third party services would not be ideal for me because:

- I would not hold the private keys to my Bitcoin Cash.
- I would pay a fee for each transaction.

Seeing this as the case, I'm only willing to use software on my own servers to accept Bitcoin Cash in a security-minded way.

**Here's my current approach:**

1. Have two servers: Server A, which runs Apache; and Server B, which runs a Bitcoin Cash wallet such a [Bitcoin Unlimited](https://www.bitcoinunlimited.info/).
2. Server A requests addresses from Server B through the JSON-RPC interface.
3. Server A displays the address to the user and pings Server B at intervals until the payment is confirmed.
4. The user sees a confirmation page and the order is complete.

**Advantages to this approach:**

- I hold my private keys.
- I would not have to "refill" the server with public keys.
- Private keys (*theoretically*) never leave Server B.

**Disadvantages:**

- Both Server A and Server B must be online in order to accept transactions.
- Server B must be configured in a way so that the commands `dumpprivkey`, `dumpwallet`, `createrawtransaction`, and `send*` are disabled. (How?)

**So, is my approach the way to go, or is there a superior alternative?**

Answer (score 0):

Your Bitcoin cash server may be a target for many since it has all the private keys.

I would suggest you get one private master key and public key.

use your public key to generate addresses and your private key to spend Bitcoins.

You can `createrawtransaction` and all the other commands using PHP or javascript without the need to have a running server.

these libraries are helpful: bitcoinlib-js for javascript and bitcoin-php for PHP

You may need a server just for broadcast a transaction if you want to send bitcoins. you could use your own server or use public servers like electrum servers or blockchain.info

Answer (score 0):

There are POS software for that. Here's the list: https://github.com/dsmurrell/awesome-bitcoin-cash#point-of-sale-systems

If you'd like to use an HD wallet, I suggest Pyxpub.